# VBS script: Error 800A01AD "ActiveX component can't create object" while opening url on browser

Tags: vbscript

I have an error 800A01AD "ActiveX component can't create object" when I execute following vbs file at the last line:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
...
objShell.Run("http://www.google.com")
```

I noticed it only happens on my computer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution: Configure missing windows default browser (a default program for http protocol is needed by the script to work properly).

For windows7:

- Click `Control Panel`.
- Click `Programs` and then `Default Programs` and then `Set your default programs`.
- On the left, select a browser.
- Click `Set this program as default`and `OK`.